# One word indicating that a process is not yet finished

Tags: single-word-requests

Any suggestion for a single word that implies: "this process is not yet finished"? I will use this in the database; it has a corresponding boolean.

Example:

`notYetFinished = true` - This indicates that it is not yet finished.

`notYetFinished = false` - This means that it is already finished.

I'm looking for a single word to use instead of **`notYetFinished`**; I would much prefer a technical word describing a process that is not yet finished, or that is on standby.

Comment: When picking a word for boolean fields, prefer the "positive" format.  In this case you can simply use "finished" with a value of true or false.  Or "inProgress".  Avoid negative terms since it becomes difficult to decipher at a glance.

Comment: +1 on using positive terms. Not Finished (or Finished = False) causes less cognitive overhead than Not Finished = True.

Comment: In a database, I'd prefer to see a test along the lines of "WHERE DateCompleted IS [NOT] NULL" to the use of a boolean but I very much agree with Kim and Laconic Drod on the importance of framing boolean names positively.

Comment: Could you not just eliminate spaces, and runwordstogether to fulfil the one word requirement within the context of a coded procedure?

Comment: While this doesn't help the request as stated, it might be better to call your variable `finished` and then your loop is `while (!finished)` which reads as, "while not finished" - which is exactly what you're going for and makes for much simpler/clearer logic.

Comment: This isn't a coding board, but... are you sure there will only ever be two states? How do you distinguish between jobs that haven't run and ones which are in progress? What if they fail?

Comment: @johncip In that case he can use an enum for the various states but now we're getting really off-topic for the English Language site!

Comment: What's wrong with "unfinished"??

Comment: @johncip My system has a function that  processes those data, then `after processing it if and only if there is no error` that I can considered it finished, other than that is considered as not yet finished, I also have plenty of functions to catch those errors while processing it. I guess boolean suits this.

Comment: @fluffy `while(isRunning)` reads "while is running". Positive, clear and legible. Has a form of "be" in a bool variable name too, which is always useful.

Comment: @StuperUser That's also an excellent approach. Basically, avoiding double-negatives is the thing I was going for, but I didn't notice that Kim had already said the same thing in a previous comment (with much better clarity as well).

Comment: @Kim - that's a tough call.  I'm not sure it's *always* better to use the positive word.  something like `while(ongoing)` is very intuitive.  I appreciate that, say, 70% of engineers use it as a "rule" what you say, and that's fair enough.

Comment: Note too that **notYetFinished** is excellent.  Code must be self-documenting.  Variable names and call names should be ridiculouslyLongAtAllTimes.  They can neverBeTooLong.  Definitely go for sentences, **not words** for variable names, always.

Comment: @JoeBlow I agree that it isn't a "rule" to use the positive. That's why I said "prefer".  I disagree that "notYetFinished" is an excellent variable name. ongoing = true (or even finished = false) is more quickly understood than notYetFinished = true.

Comment: Hi Kim ... for sure, that makes sense what you say.  I'd suggest, it would be clearer with more context.  I suggest that "not yet finished" may, indeed, be the clearest expression in certain algorithms.  (Then again, I use goto in certain algorithms - opinions differ, right?! :)  )  Cheers...

Answer (score 61):

Ongoing [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ongoing)

> *adjective* Being actually in process

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean *adjective* rather than *noun*?

Comment: That's the word we all came here looking for. "Ongoing"? Check.

Answer (score 43):

These seem very obvious:

**incomplete**

**unfinished**

Comment: Unfinished is the most obvious one. "Active" would be another choice.

All these suggestions carry the implication that the task has already started but is not yet finished. If the task is waiting to start, then "pending" might be a good description.

Comment: @IanShaw: Your comment really should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: An **incomplete** process isn't necessarily ongoing or in-progress imho, it can also be *suspended*, *scheduled*, *blocked* etc.

Comment: @Alok, the same is true for "not yet finished." These suggestions are fine.

Comment: @user1717828 I just realized, my comment is a bit unclear - I'm actually supporting this answer and upvoted it. I was actually pointing out that some other answers like in progress, underway etc. aren't as suitable as this one.

Answer (score 33):

How about **pending**?

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pending) defines pending as:

> Awaiting decision or settlement

Comment: pending completion?

Comment: I think `pending` is fine and often used in programming. The question is about a word that implies "this process is not yet finished". As a programmer in this case I would probably go for something like `pendingProcess` but even as a single word I think `pending` works just fine.

Comment: To me, "Not Yet Finished" implies that it has started, but hasn't finished yet. "Pending" implies that it hasn't even started. Pending may be sufficient, or even correct, for their purposes, but the two don't have the same meaning.

Comment: _Pending_ could also mean "not yet started".  I would avoid this vague term, especially in light of the other good suggestions here.

Comment: Pending means waiting in a queue or waiting for something to happen before it starts.

Comment: "*[**Pending** — awaiting decision or settlement.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+pending)*": There's nothing wrong with pending for something that has or hasn't started, IMO: it doesn't necessarily imply not started, merely unfinished.

Comment: @anotherdave: In computer software and processes it almost always means "unstarted". The rest of the time it's ambiguous. Either way, it doesn't fit the question.

Comment: I'd disagree — e.g. Chrome Dev Tools uses it in this sense for AJAX requests that haven't returned; less technically, Facebook uses it for Friend Requests that have been initiated but not actioned on the other end. Think it could be applicable in this case, if the OP does care about making a distinction regarding whether it has started or not

Answer (score 18):

***in progress*** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20progress)

Definition:

> happening or being done

Example:

> *Several projects are now in progress.*

Comment: +1 for "In progress" because it is a database, and nothing gets more to the point than "In progress." If this were a literary work or some kind of manual I might've suggested something else, but since this goes in a database which may very well be inherited by another individual, you don't want them guessing what each state is.

Comment: inprogress would by the one word form of the term?

Comment: @Stan It's not one word. You could camelCase it for a database, of course: inProgress.

Answer (score 15):

Easy solution:

Drop the "notyet" from the term you're using already, reverse the boolean operators, and you're ***finished***.

Thus:

finished = true (It's finished)

finished = false (It's not finished)

For a more technical term you could replace the easily understood with something else such as ***complete*** or ***done*** or even ***effectuated***. : )

Comment: I agree whole heartedly.  I've never understood the tendency to use double negatives like this, but I see it all of the time. "Yes, we have no bananas" anyone?

Comment: The only problem with this is that finished doesn't give you any information about whether the operation has started

Comment: @Ben Really? Isn't the enquiry about the status of an event imply that it exists—and if it exists, that it had been started in order to exist?

Answer (score 14):

How about "***[underway](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/under-way?q=underway)***"?:

> Having started and in progress; being done or carried out.

Answer (score 10):

[**Processing**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/process)

> a series of actions that produce something or that lead to a particular result

*Merriam-Webster*

It's worth noting that answers for this question are a little tricky in that words that literally mean 'not yet complete' are not as satisfactory from a programming perspective as a word that doesn't exactly fit the definition but describes what is happening much better.

Comment: Agreed. It's not just about satisfying English. Coding has its own jargon, and for unfinished jobs are typically described as unprocessed (or pending), or processing, depending on status. Or you can go more specific if the job warrants it, e.g. "rendering."

Comment: Double agreed -- in a software engineering context, those words (or "busy" / "working" / "running" ) might make more sense as an answer to the question as written than they would in other contexts.  Also avoiding the double-negative definitely improves readability/maintainability, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

> I would much prefer a technical word describing a process that is not
>   yet finished, or that is on standby.

If you are going to use it for coding purpose:

```
while(running) {
 // do something
}
```

word you are looking for is 'running'.

Answer (score 3):

*Outstanding*

> Continuing to exist, unresolved

[Definition 2 at MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outstanding)

Answer (score 1):

**wip**

Abbreviation of the phrase: *work in progress*

If you need a short word to use for your situation, you could use an abbreviation like *wip*, witch stands for 'work in progress'.

Comment: I don't think abbreviations are good in code (or databases), with the odd exception, of-course (`id`, `ok`, etc).  I once worked on a database with column names such as `QQSID`, `QQSQSID`, `QQSSQID`, `QQSISID`.  Makes things very hard to read, annoying, and even with easier to read ones if you don't know it, you have to look it up.

Comment: WIP is a well known business acronym for project planning and also in accounting (see http://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/workinprogress.asp). Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_in_process) *"Work in progress or work in process is the general description of a partially finished project."*

Comment: Working on a project with ambiguous acronyms sounds like a huge pain. That being said, those are the trade offs a project team should be aware they are making. I've seen really expressive codes that are practically unintelligible: P = I*V, or Power = Current * Voltage, or PowerOurputIdealFuelCell = CurrentOutputIdealFuelCell * VoltageOutputIdealUsingThompsonModel. Even though the last is the most descriptive, I would argue to use the first or second

Answer (score 1):

Boolean variables are more readable when they start with "is."

For your case, I'd recommend "isInProgress" or "isOngoing."

Comment: `IsComplete` would be my choice -- although more likely I would do this with a lookup status table and a tinyint to identify all the different stages of doneness

Comment: This is English Language not Programming.  IsInProgress is not a word, it's a camel-case identifier.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: True, but op's question was in a programming context. He was actually looking for an identifier, not an English word.

Comment: @USER_8675309: You're right, IsComplete would be more understandable, but op asked for its negation.

Comment: @wcr4 A kinder interpretation of the OP's question is that they are looking for a single word to *replace* a camel case identifier.  If that is correct, then the question is in the right place.  If they are looking for an identifier that is not an English word, then this is not the place for that question, or your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with **busy**. If something hasn't finished what it's doing yet, then I think it's accurately described as being busy.

Note though that I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

**finalized**

> To put in final or finished form.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finalized

As an aside: booleans need not be stated in the positive (for example, consider a database column named `INACTIVE`) However, as others have mentioned, in this case, stating your booleans in the positive is perhaps clearer.

Following your original logic, you could use `incomplete` just as well as `notYetFinished`.

Answer (score 1):

As Kim pointed out, double-negatives can be confusing.

```
notYetFinished = false
```

Wait what?

So like Kim, I would propose a positive word: **done**

```
done = false

// ...

done = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a noun rarely used in this sense you can try **arrear**(usually used in plural).

> An unfinished duty. (Check definition at [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrear))

Comment: It's an obscure enough word that I think this term would decrease legibility and comprehension.  I would not be happy to see it as a db column.

Comment: Arrears sounds to me like things unfinished and left behind, something that should have been done but is still not - Indeed it is used for overdue amounts and it has the same root as the Italian "arretrati" (backlog). Not what the querent was looking for, which is "this process is still running, it is not finished _yet_", IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

For a computer process, it is common to use

**executing**

> carry out an instruction or program.

a process that is not finished, but is on 'standby' as you mentioned is

**ready**

> in a suitable state for an activity, action, or situation; fully prepared.

could also apply

**working**

> functioning or able to function.

General Process State Diagram:

[image]

Comment: The diagram suggests "running" instead of "executing".

Answer (score -1):

Undone.

Though would suggest a field that means 'done' over a field that means 'not done,' given the acrobatics of logic required.

Comment: "undone" to me implies it used to be done, but *came undone*.

Answer (score -1):

Active:

> engaging or ready to engage in physically energetic pursuits.
>
> participating or engaged in a particular sphere or activity.

Progressing:

> moving toward a goal or to a further or higher stage